# Thread doesn't continue upon resume computer

Tags: c#, tcp

I connect to a client using `TcpClient.BeginConnect` where i have a loop that is running as long as a `CancellationToken` isn't requested cancelled.

```
while (!_token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    var s = reader.ReadLine() ?? string.Empty;
}
```

I also reconnect and handle exceptions with logging.

When I start this application everything works as expected. However, when I put my computer to sleep and wake it up again it seems all the threads have terminated.

The workflow is as follows:

1. I start (from the main thread) a new Task which executes `DoWork`. I execute like this: `Task.Run(()=>DoWork(),_token);`
2. `DoWork` instantiates a new `TcpClient` and initiates a `BeginConnect` like this:

`(_client = new TcpClient()).BeginConnect(Address, Port, ConnectCallback, _client);`

3. Within `ConnectCallback` I have a *while* statement which keeps reading data from the stream (see above).

Any idea what happens to the threads when the computer goes to sleep?

Comment: Probably the underlying socket "die"

Comment: How do you handle the reconnection to the network on wake?

Comment: I do not explicitly handle any *wake* signal, but the whole *while* statement is withing a *try/catch/finally* block which should handle the reconnect. However, nothing is being logged. I even have enabled logging within the loop every 10 seconds.

Comment: What's to prevent the thread from staying blocked in `ReadLine` forever? TCP does not guarantee that a connection loss can be detected by a side that does not send data.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Agreed. If it is staying in `ReadLine` for (up to the TCP Idle Session Timeout), that does imply that no attempt is being made to send data, as you point out. Having one (or both) sides send a keep-alive datum regularly could be a solution; remote disconnection will be detected much sooner once the client realises it can't send any data. But perhaps still not soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

When your computer wakes from a sleep, the connections will sometimes (but not always) be severed. It depends on a number of factors, some of which might not be under your control.

In terms of your callback method, there is no exception triggered but `reader.EndOfStream` will be true when the connection has ended and all prior data has been read. **Edit:** However, if the TCP stack is unaware that the remote has disconnected, this call will block until data arrives, the `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` period has passed, or until the TCP session idle timeout, whichever happens first.

(**Edit:** If no data is sent, the connection will only end automatically if the TCP stack is aware (based on its own network state detection, or TCP packets) that the remote has disconnected; otherwise it will wait until session idle timeout, which can take up to an hour or so, depending on the client. One solution is for the client to send data regularly (if it has not received data recently) to act as a kind of early disconnection detection.)

In fact when the connection ends (e.g. after your computer wakes up), the `while` loop you posted would go into a tight loop, maxing out a CPU core, because `reader.ReadLine()` keeps returning `null`. You can check for that and break out of the loop:

```
if (reader.EndOfStream)
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: I check for reader.EndOfStream first thing in the loop - which does not trigger. For debugging purposes I've created a timer which starts prior to reading a line from the stream, and is stopped afterwards. This timer is triggered after the specified time, so I can detect when something has happened. But how do I shut down the defective thread?

Comment: Don't write code that waits forever unless you actually want to wait forever. This is really a case of "write code that does what you want".

Comment: I don't see what you mean by this.

Comment: @Vincent If you already check for `reader.EndOfStream`, can you update the question accordingly? This and any other missing code could be crucial in us being able to replicate your exact problem. I tried to reproduce the problem you reported on sleep/wake based on code available and for me, the connection terminated immediately upon wake and `reader.EndOfStream` was true.

Comment: @wardies do you use any publicly available service to connect to which regularly sends data? If so, I could create a sample and connect to this.

Comment: @Vincent I tested by connecting to both local LAN and internet-based web servers on port 80 and writing `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n")` to the stream, then calling `Flush()` on the stream. This ensured the remote web server kept the connection open for a period long enough to do some quick tests.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem (although not a nice one) was to use a timer which explicitly closed the connection after a given amount of time.

```
var timeoutTimer = new Timer(state =>
{
    var temp = (TcpClient)state;
    Log.Error("Read timeout. Closing connection.");
    temp.Close();
}, client, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Prior to accessing the stream I activate this timer:

```
timeoutTimer.Change(20000, Timeout.Infinite); // Handle timeouts.
```

And reset it afterwards:

```
timeoutTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite); // Reset timeout.
```

Both using reader.EndOfStream or reader.ReadLine causes the thread to stop at that point, which isn't resolved unless the connetion is forcefully terminated.

**EDIT:**
Setting TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout does the same thing as above - probably better. Throws an IOException when the reciever does not receive any data for the specified amount of time (in ms).

Comment: Cannot replicate your last statement; for me, both return immediately. Please include more code, e.g. how do you create the `reader` instance? This could be critical to explaining why you're seeing what you're seeing but others do not.

Comment: Actually, it's more likely to be down to the nature of your local environment and the thing you are connecting to. So it probably won't help to see the whole code. The solution you've found makes sense but perhaps you can more simply set the `TcpClient.ReceiveTimeout` property?